Strongly convex function equivalence
Say f is a $\mu$ strongly convex function, then i know, using Cauchy Schwarz, that it implies that $|| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \geq \mu || x - y||$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$
Say now that the function verifies this property for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, is it true that that it also implies that f is $\mu$ strongly convex ( i tried it different ways, but it seems that this condition is too strong to prove the implication back).
Is this equivalence a thing or only the first implication holds ?

indeed, thanks a lot ! Going to close the question ...

Did you forget a square in your question? $f(x) = x^2$ is $2$-strongly convex, and yet $|f(x)-f(0)| < 2|x-0|$ for any $0 < x < 1$

Oops sorry, realized that it is the derivative of f and not f

Now with your new question, $f(x) = -x^2$ is not strongly convex (it is even concave) but it satisfies your condition with $\mu = 2$

yes indeed, thanks a lot !

If $f$ is strongly convex then $-f$ is strongly concave and satisfies the same inequality.

And if you already know that $f$ is convex and it satisfies this inequality, it is indeed $\mu$-strongly convex.
